# Yahoo is asking me for security questions and I do not remember the answers to them.

Tags: security, yahoo, login, yahoo-messenger

I had an Yahoo account which I haven't accessed for months, and now when I try to log in again Yahoo asks me to answer two security questions, which I don't remember. Let's face it, everyone enters some random string in those fields when they are completing their registration process.

**I know my password** and they don't let me log in before I tell them what's my pets name is (which would be hardly secure since every friend would know my pet name). I contacted their "customer care" and got no reply.

Is there anything I can do to get my account back?
I only needed it for the Yahoo Messenger service (with Pidgin)...

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting a new password by using the "Forgot Password" feature that'll send a link to alternative email address or phone number.
and if you don't even have access to those I'm afraid only customer care can help you.